# how to exclude httpinvoker package from spring-framework/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/remoting/httpinvoker/ at runtime in jboss

Tags: httpinvoker

How to exclude httpinvoker package spring-web at runtime in jboss server ?

In the sonatype scan found the one issue about the httpinvoker package, instead of httpinvoker we created new code to make call. so we need to exclude the same package from the spring-web